# Any way to find out what my shared hosting "lag" is?

Tags: performance, hosting, shared, lag

I have shared hosting with hostgator and until about a month ago, things were dandy.  Now.. every 2 to 3 minutes, I'll click a link and the browser won't resolve for about a full minute.  This is any of my sites.. and links that are both database calls or very simply html hyperlinks.  It's with any browser and at work or home.

I've opened 2 tickets with hostgator and they swear all their tests show that there are no problems, but.. I get this over and over and over again.. and have for weeks now.

Is there any kind of error outputting I could do.. or tools of any kind that would allow me to troubleshoot this myself?

Comment: I think this question should be posted at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about other browsers, but Google Chrome has a tool to measure the time a website took to load. Click the wrench icon in the top right, then go to Tools -> Developer Tools. Then you will see a new section at the bottom of the screen. Click the Network tab and it will show you a lot of data about the latency etc. It will also show you which file is the one that is taking the longest. Hope this helps.

Comment: Neat tool.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

From a console on the server itself, use the wget command to pull a page. Do it periodically in a script, logging to a file. Put it in cron. That'll show you if there are any lag issues with the server itself. If that looks good, then it's somewhere in the network. You could do a similar test from another box on another provider, which if comes up clean, points to your ISP or DNS as the culprit.